# Настройки интеграции фб пиксель

Tags: facebook, интеграция

Нужна помощь в настройки интеграции фб пиксель - партнёрская сеть на базе аланбейс - бот в тг
Возможно предложение других вариантов интеграции
В общем есть продукт (телеграм-бот), есть партнерская система аланбейс и соответственно имеются партнеры, которые хотят предоставлять трафик и необходимо сделать так, чтобы они могли получать данные с бота по статистике в Facebook Pixel